# Is there any plugin in jmeter for for checking the connectivity alone (able to connect particular host ad port is success/failure)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there any plugin in jmeter for for checking the connectivity alone (able to connect particular host ad port is success/failure) and not the load. I am pretty new to jmeter. But when i researched i found that There is a plugin in jmeter - PerfMon Server Agent. It can be used for server monitoring. but i need particulerly to check only connectivity. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you need the plugin when JMeter already comes with [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler)? Example below configuration tests connectivity with `example.com` host on port 80

   [image: JMeter TCP Sampler Check Connectivity]

   Sampler will pass if it will be able to establish the connection with given host and port and otherwise fail. You can learn more about TCP Sampler usage from [How to Load Test TCP Protocol Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter)
2. As an alternative you can use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), equivalent [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code would be something like:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
   import java.net.Socket

   Socket s = null;

   try {
       s = new Socket('example.com', 80)
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)   
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage(ex.getMessage())
   }
   finally {
       IOUtils.closeQuietly(s)
   }
   ```

Comment: I am getting 500 error when i run the test according to given link. Please help me

Comment: how ever i am geeting the message i am sending in tcp sampler